# What is the smallest $n$ such that $BB(n) > $Graham's number?

Tags: turing-machines, busy-beaver

BB represents the busy beaver function here. Do we even have any idea of what order of magnitude $n$ would have? Is it possibly around 10, or more like 1000?

Comment: It was long time ago (do not have link) anyway fast check gives [n = 19](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Wythagoras/The_nineteenth_Busy_Beaver_number_is_greater_than_Graham's_Number!?useskin=oasis) but I didn't run this one.

Comment: @Evil Oh my apologies

Comment: It is, of course, BB(8).

Comment: @wogsland Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Ovi No, but I have a force....

Comment: @wogsland Haha I googled BB(8) star wars and found the robot but I don't see a connection with Graham's number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly it started with [$n = 64$](https://sites.google.com/site/res0001/surpassing-graham-s-number), then [$n = 25$](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Deedlit11/Okay,_more_Turing_machines) shortly after that with $n=23$, [$n = 22$](https://sites.google.com/site/pointlesslargenumberstuff/home/l/timeline) and now [$n = 19$](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Wythagoras/The_nineteenth_Busy_Beaver_number_is_greater_than_Graham's_Number!?useskin=oasis).

Comment: ... and now [$n=16$](https://www.sligocki.com/2022/07/11/bb-16-graham.html).